# FFmpeg : How to create dynamic volume changes in an audio file?

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg

I am working on a project in which I need to change the volume of an audio file dynamically.

Let's say, I have an audio file with name xyz.mp3 (20 - seconds audio file).
I need to set the volume in it like :

```
Time Range (in Seconds)     ||     Volume Percentage (in %)
-------------------------------------------------------------------    
    0 - 4                   ||           100
                            ||
    4 - 8                   ||    change from 100 - 20 (dynamically)
                            ||
    8 - 12                  ||           20
                            ||           
    12 - 16                 ||    change from 20 - 100 (dynalically)
                            ||
    16 - 20                 ||           100
```

Now, I know that to change the volume for a particular time in audio, I can use the following command :

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -af volume=20:enable='between(t,8,12)' out.mp3
```

but when I use volume effect, it does not change the volume dynamically. It just straightly change volume from 100 to 20 and not change it like fading.

and When I use afade command like :

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -af afade=t=in:ss=4:d=8,afade=t=out:st=12:d=16 out.mp3
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -af afade=enable='between(t,4,8)':t=in:ss=4:d=4,afade=enable='between(t,12,16)':t=out:st=12:d=4 out.mp3
```

but it looks that afade does not work multiple times even when I am using ffmpeg 3.0.1 version.

As afade only works single time, I had also split my audio into parts of 4 second and add fade effects to it and then combine them again, but there is some milliseconds gap comes between each clip. Does anyone know a better way to do it? Please help me...

**Update 1 :**

Here is that code I used :

```
"volume='" +
            "between(t,0,8)+(1-0.8*(t-8)/4)*" +        // full
            "between(t,8.01,11.99)+0.1*" +             // change from HIGH -> LOW
            "between(t,12,16)+(0.1+0.8*(t-16)/4)*" +   // low
            "between(t,16.01,19.99)+1*" +              // change from LOW -> HIGH   -
            "between(t,20,24)+(1-0.8*(t-24)/4)*" +     // full
            "between(t,24.01,27.99)+0.1*"+             // change from HIGH -> LOW   -
            "between(t,28,32)+(0.1+0.8*(t-32)/4)*" +   // low
            "between(t,32.01,35.99)+1*" +              // change from LOW -> HIGH  -
            "between(t,36,40)+(1-0.8*(t-40)/4)*" +     // full
            "between(t,40.01,43.99)+0.1*"+             // change from HIGH -> LOW   -
            "between(t,44,48)+(0.1+0.8*(t-48)/4)*" +   // low
            "between(t,48.01,51.99)+" +                // change from LOW -> HIGH -
            "between(t,52,56)" +                       // high
            "':eval=frame";
```

In this code, I got a small (some milliseconds gap) at those places where I initialize the audio to change the volume

**Update 2**
Ok I got it, I just need to change the time values like  19.99 to 19.9999 and 16.01 to 16.0001 and it solve the problem. Thank You Gyaan Sir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
volume='between(t,0,4)+(1-0.8*(t-4)/4)*between(t,4.01,7.99)+0.2*between(t,8,12)+(0.2+0.8*(t-12)/4)*between(t,12.01,15.99)+between(t,16,20)':eval=frame
```

Comment: Okk Wait I will try it... till that can you please explain about this line a bit more?

Comment: The volume expression has a set of chained expressions, whose result is applied to the audio frame with the given timestamp. See http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation

Comment: Hey Gyan Sir, I had tested this code and find that it is working and changing the volume but there are some little gaps (fluctuations) created in final audio. I am updating my Q and here I am adding the method I used...

Comment: The gap in the audio is just like some disturbance. It can easily be recognized by the audience. Please check my code and help me in find bug.

Comment: The gaps might happen because e.g. the time range `between(t,4.01,7.99)` equals to `3.98` and not `4`. I believe that part before it should say `(t-4)/3.98)*be…`.